# Winform:TreeView Node Collapse without Node Click event firing

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, click

I need to prevent a click event occurring on a node when its collapsed. I still want the node to collapse and hide all the children under it but I don't want the click event being fired or the node selected if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to influence you own code you can use a flag like this:

```
bool suppressClick = false;

private void treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (suppressClick) return;
    // else your regular code..
}

private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.IsExpanded)
         { suppressClick = false; }
    else { suppressClick = true; }
}
```

For more control you may need to get at the windows message queue..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to used the former solution but it only worked one way. I implement a dictionary where I keep the nodes expanded/collapse stated, so when I found the state is the same it is a actual node click and not a collapsing/expanding behaviour.

```
public class Yourclass {  

       var nodeStates = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

         public void addNode(Yourentity entity) 
         {
              TreeNode node= new TreeNode(entity.Name);
              node.Tag = entity;
              tree.Nodes.Add(entity);
              nodeStates.Add(entity.Id, true /* expanded in this case but doesn't matter */);
         }

       private void TreeControl_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
         var entity = (Yourentity )e.Node.Tag;
         bool state = nodeStates[entity.Id];

         // If was expanded or collapsed values will be different
         if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0 && (e.Node.IsExpanded != state))
         {
            // We update the state
             nodeStates[entity.Id] = e.Node.IsExpanded;
             return;
         }

         /* Put here your actual node click code */
     }
}
```